# Background view not scaling correctly in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

that for some reason, the background image on each page is about 3/4 of the way across and stretched at the top, almost like it's portrait instead of landscape, this was fine before iOS 10 / XCode 8

I am calling a lot of values from the Util file, here;

```
static float getDevicePosX( float PadPosX )
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    CGRect f = appDelegate.window.frame;
    float width = f.size.width > f.size.height ? f.size.width : f.size.height;
    return PadPosX / 2.0f * width / 1024.0f;
}

static float getDevicePosY( float PadPosY )
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CGRect f = appDelegate.window.frame;
    float height = f.size.width < f.size.height ? f.size.width : f.size.height;
    return PadPosY / 2.0f * height / 768.0f;
}

static float getDevicePosW( float PadPosW )
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CGRect f = appDelegate.window.frame;
    float height = f.size.width < f.size.height ? f.size.width : f.size.height;
    return PadPosW / 2.0f * height / 768.0f;
}

static float getDevicePosH( float PadPosH )
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CGRect f = appDelegate.window.frame;
    float height = f.size.width < f.size.height ? f.size.width : f.size.height;
    return PadPosH / 2.0f * height / 768.0f;
}
```

The other buttons are generally all in the correct places, it just seems to be the background image files that are the problem.

An example of how I initialise one of the backgrounds is this;

```
UIImage* imageBackground = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo_background"];
    UIImageView *viewBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
    [viewBackground setImage:imageBackground];
    [self.view addSubview: viewBackground];
```

Exact calling is;

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        UIImage* imageBackground = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo_background"];
        UIImageView *viewBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
        [viewBackground setImage:imageBackground];
        [self.view addSubview: viewBackground];

        UIImage* imageNameText = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo_name_textfield"];
        UIImage* imageNameLabel = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo_namelabel"];
        UIImage* imageNextButton = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo_next_button"];
```

Comment: `UIImage* imageBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:` do you do this in viewDidload? If so it's too early in iOS10. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885012/xcode-8-autolayouts-issue/39889248#39889248

Comment: It is yes, updated my original question, I tried delaying it as per your link but still the same?

Comment: Does this work `UIImageView *viewBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using a combination of the answer posted above by norders, but what to do is this;

Swap

```
UIImageView *viewBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
```

With

```
UIImageView *viewBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

But add the following to the top level view,

```
+ (CGRect)screenBounds {
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bounds.size = [self screenSize];
    return bounds;
}

+ (CGSize)screenSizeForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        UIInterfaceOrientation current = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(current)) {
            return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) ? screenSize : CGSizeMake(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
        } else {
            return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) ? CGSizeMake(screenSize.height, screenSize.width) : screenSize;
        }
    } else {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) ? CGSizeMake(screenSize.height, screenSize.width) : screenSize;
    }
}

+ (CGRect)screenBoundsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bounds.size = [self screenSizeForOrientation:orientation];
    return bounds;
}

+ (CGSize)screenSize {
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    if ((NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        return CGSizeMake(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
    } else {
        return screenSize;
    }
}
```

I credit this fix to a website, I found whilst searching the answer, here;

http://perrymitchell.net/article/ios-screen-size-bounds-normalisation/

Thank you to norders also.